# Azure AD / Entra ID: Getting the name of the application in the access token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, token, microsoft-entra-id

I'm using Microsoft Azure Entra ID to authenticate my background application against my API using the client credentials flow.

```
var clientId = "GUID1";
var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/GUID2";
var secret = "VerySecret";
var scope = new[] { "api://GUID3/.default" };

var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .WithAuthority(authority)
    .WithClientSecret(secret)
    .Build();
    
var authResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scope).ExecuteAsync();

var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadJwtToken(authResult.AccessToken);
new ClaimsIdentity(token.Claims).Dump();
```

The authentication process is working just fine.
However I want to get the applications name from the token, but it does not have a `name` claim, only `appid` and `oid` are present which are the IDs of the application registration and the managed Enterprise application.

I tried adding the `upn` claim as optional token, but since `upn` is the user principal name and we do not have a user here, it does not get added to the token.

```
"optionalClaims": {
    "idToken": [
        {
            "name": "upn",
            "source": null,
            "essential": false,
            "additionalProperties": []
        }
    ],
    "accessToken": [
        {
            "name": "upn",
            "source": null,
            "essential": false,
            "additionalProperties": []
        }
    ],
    "saml2Token": []
},
```

I also tried adding `name` as optional token, but was unable to save the manifest.

What is needed to add the name of the application to the token?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we can't add custom claims into Azure ad access token. If it proved to be impossible finally, we might use [graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) to get the application name.

[image]

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_id";
var clientId = "azure_ad_app_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var application = await graphClient.Applications["azure_ad_object_id_but_not_the_app_id"].Request().GetAsync();
```

[image]